# UI inside of an ASP.net API Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I built an ASP.net Web API 2 with Identity 2.0 authentication in a solution so external vendors can dump data into our database for analysis.  I built another MVC solution to connect to the same Identity database and manage the users for the Web API so our internal users can add and delete users. However, my boss told me today that the best practice is to build the UI Management(MVC) right inside the Web API project(Not Solution). I'm perplex, Is that the best way or keep the two solutions separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use case calls for a separate web application due to differences in the [NFRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement).

The API is external. The MVC UI is internal. So they have different security requirements-- the MVC app is more sensitive, and may need to be secured via different means, e.g. AD integration. The API will need to sit in your DMZ to be accessible to the public while the MVC application could sit on an internal network.

The API is for public consumption, so may have different availability requirements. The API is probably 24/7/365 while the internal app can be brought down for maintenance without impacting anyone but your administrators. The API probably needs to designed to scale out-- meaning load balancing-- while the admin site could possibly run on a single web server, and could therefore be stateful without requiring IP stickiness.

The deployment schedule is different. The API will change when system features change. The MVC UI will change only when administrative functions change. You may want to be able to upgrade one while leaving the other one alone.

There is no reason to lock these applications together, and there are many reasons not to. It is definitely not best practice to combine them.